# How to raise new event that triggered from 1 of multi instances of child-class in VBA?

Tags: vba, class, event-handling

I have example clsChild in VBA which have nothing than 1 var and 1 event

```
Private V#
Public Event Change()
Public Property Get Value()
 Value = V
End Property
Public Property Let Value(inp#)
 V = inp
 RaiseEvent Change
End Property
```

then I create another class called clsParent, which have multi instances of clsChild:

```
Public ListofChild()
Public Event ParentChange()
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 redim Listofchild(1 to 3)
 set listofchild(1) = new clsChild
 set listofchild(2) = new clsChild
 set listofchild(3) = new clsChild
End Sub
```

How could I raise parentChange event when 1 of those instances of clsChild change (known by change event of clsChild)?

Comment: This can’t be both vb.net and vba.. please only select one

Comment: either is ok, I think I just need a concept for that, coding not much different between vb.net and vba

Comment: 1 posible way I could think is make a objParent in clsChild and then refer to it and active parentChange from each clsChild, but it look like a work-around to me... and it could lead to reference bug between 2 obj in vba in complex situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WithEvents` reference to each child object in your parent class in order to be able to capture and handle its events.

```
Public Event ParentChange()

Private WithEvents objChild As clsChild

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 Set objChild = new clsChild
End Sub

'EventHandler
Private Sub objChild_Change()
    RaiseEvent ParentChange
    Debug.Print "Change event handled."
End Sub
```

*WithEvents* can only be declared at module level in Class modules.

Once you prefix an object with the *WithEvents* keyword, the object's events are listed in the events combo in VBE. Prefixing an object with the *WithEvents* keyword while the object has no events, a compile error occurs.

You can find plenty of resources online. See another example [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/213566/how-to-create-application-level-event-handlers-in-excel).

Comment: but this will only work on specified number of clsChild, If I have multi clsChild ??
like an array of 100 instances of clsChild, what will I do ? write 100 lines of WithEvents ?? I know how to use Event, but I don't know how to handle unknow number of instances

Comment: Okay, now I see what you mean. You could create a events class, instantiate it in parent and pass to each child through an `Init()` method. The child then calls methods of the class which in return raise events.

Comment: My intend is just when I change a value of 1 instance of clsChild, the parent will know clsChild Changed and active 1 sub/function to recalculate its value by sum all value of those clsChild. but it even more complicate, I content those clsChild inside 1 of my custom class, it's list class - clsList (which don't exist in vba, so I write 1).
I feel headache already =.= those vba not clearly and easy to write as vb.net and c# too much limitations...